# How do I increase the cell width of the ipython notebook in Enthought Canopy?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, canopy

I'd like to increase the cell width in the the Enthought Canopy (v1.5.2) browser and it seems simply changing the custom.css is insufficient.  Does anyone know how to do this?

I've tried [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24207353/2108548) which works on Anaconda but not on Enthought (which supplies its own lightweight browser).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Canopy provides two ways of running the IPython notebook. As you've observed, the notebook that runs inside the Canopy editor has some constraints (a trade-off for the convenience of Canopy GUI integration). As an alternative, you can run the full notebook in your standard browser: From the Canopy Tools menu, open a Canopy Command Prompt (or Canopy Terminal), then `ipython notebook`. This has the additional advantage that it can use the latest versions of IPython (after updating them), see [this article](https://support.enthought.com/entries/22305234-IPython-Installed-version-in-the-Package-Manager-is-not-being-used-in-the-Canopy-GUI).

Comment: Thank you Jonathan.  Indeed running ipython notebook from the command prompt shows that the suggestion from the above linked post works.  One thing to note: updating to Canopy version 1.5.2 and rebooting my windows machine also worked.  I had not rebooted since updating from 1.4 -- I guess that was required somehow.  So it appears that the later version of Canopy does respect the solution from the linked post in my original question.

Comment: Just to be clear.  Using windows 7 and editing `%HOME%\.ipython\profile_default\static\custom\custom.css` did nothing when I restarted the Canopy editor.  However, when I edited 

`%HOME%\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.2.2785.win-x86_64\Lib\site-packages\canopy\notebook\static\custom\custom.css`

with

`.container { width:95% !important; }`

I got the desired behavior.  Note: I had to completely restart Canopy to get this going.