# How do I increase the cell width of the ipython notebook in my browser? (Both Python 2 and 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, jupyter

I followed the instructions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971449/how-do-i-increase-the-cell-width-of-the-ipython-notebook-in-my-browser)
and they worked like a charm... for Python 2. But not for Python 3.

I'm running Anaconda on Windows. To activate Python 2 from the command prompt I type

```
 activate python2
```

So, when I type

```
 jupyter notebook
```

*after* having activated Python 2, the Jupyter notebook that pops up is affected by my **custom.css** file (and it runs Python 2). But if I start the Jupyter notebook *without* having activated Python 2 (which results in the Jupyter Notebook running Python 3), the notebook looks the default way. What can I do?

Comment: Please, provide more context. Do you have a conda-env running python2?, do you have a conda-env running python3? is it jupyter installed on both envs?, where is your *custom.css* located?,...

Comment: @kikocorreoso I'm not sure how Anaconda manages environments, but I think I have two 'envs', one for Python 2 and one for Python 3, with the latter being the 'default' one, since it's the one that I 'get' when I open the command prompt. Jupyter is installed in both. My custom.css is located at `~/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom/custom.css`