# How to set max output width in numpy?

Tags: python, css, numpy, ipython

I am using a Jupyter notebook. I have a pretty wide screen, but the displayed output (say, when I print a `numpy` array) is formatted as if the screen was narrow.

I found a way of increasing the width of the cells, with

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML("<style>.container { width:95% !important; }</style>")
```

but this seems to influence the input only, not the output (see screenshots):

[image: short input]
[image: longer input]

I've tried setting the `linewidth` option in `numpy.set_printoptions`, I've tried setting `numpy.core.arrayprint._line_width`, nothing...

EDIT: Using matplotlib I can set the width of plots (that I plot in the notebook with the magic `%matplotlib inline`) with the command `plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=[X,Y]`. It turns out that I can increase `X` to have plots fill the output cell horizontally all the way. This means (I think) that the original problem it's a `numpy` thing.

Comment: [Have you seen this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971449/how-do-i-increase-the-cell-width-of-the-jupyter-ipython-notebook-in-my-browser)

Comment: For the reader that arrived from searching about *Pandas*, you can use these two lines:
`pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 50)

pd.set_option('display.width', 120)`

Comment: Quick one-liner to have longgggggg lines and remove the scientific notation: `np.set_printoptions(suppress=True, linewidth=100000)`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is a year old now but maybe the answer will help someone else.

The way numpy-arrays are displayed depends on a number of things.
With this code, you can show more items and use the full width of your screen:

This is the default

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(edgeitems=3)
np.core.arrayprint._line_width = 80

>>> array([[[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
>>>    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
>>>    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
>>>    ...,
```

With the following code you increase the items shown at the edge of each array (start and end) as well as the line width:

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(edgeitems=10)
np.core.arrayprint._line_width = 180

>>> array([[[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
>>>         [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
>>>         [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
```

Comment: numpy version 1.16.2 on python 3.7.3: `np.set_printoptions(edgeitems=10,linewidth=180)`

Answer (score 80):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21529105/625919) helpful in creating my own:

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(edgeitems=30, linewidth=100000, 
    formatter=dict(float=lambda x: "%.3g" % x))
```

The absurd linewidth means only `edgeitems` and the window's width will determine when newlines/wrapping occurs.

[image]

If I shrink the window a bit, it looks like this, so you may still need to play with the `edgeitems` or formatting:

[image]

[Here are the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) for `set_printoptions`, of which the following are relevant:

- `edgeitems` : Number of array items in summary at beginning and end of each dimension (default 3).
- `linewidth` : The number of characters per line for the purpose of inserting line breaks (default 75).

Comment: To temporarily change the option, use `with np.printoptions(youroption=):`. See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html#numpy.set_printoptions

Comment: the `formatter` is the critical part that makes the other two work. so nice