# Setting display width for OpenAI Gym (now Gymnasium)

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm trying to print out some values in Gymnasium (previously OpenAI Gym), such as:

```
import gymnasium as gym
env = gym.make("LunarLander-v2", render_mode="human")
observation, info = env.reset()

print(f'env.observation_space: {env.observation_space}')
print(f'obs: {observation}')
```

The output looks like:

```
env.observation_space: Box([-90.        -90.         -5.         -5.         -3.1415927  -5.
  -0.         -0.       ], [90.        90.         5.         5.         3.1415927  5.
  1.         1.       ], (8,), float32)

obs: [-0.00316305  1.3999956  -0.3203935  -0.48554128  0.00367194  0.072574
  0.          0.        ]
```

Is there any way to set options such as `set_option('display.max_columns', 500)` or
`set_option('display.width', 1000)` like Pandas?

<sub>- The tag should be `Gymnasium` but there's only `openai-gym` right now, so I'm using it.</sub>
 <sub>- I'm not sure if StackOverflow is the right place to ask this question, but there are many questions like this and helpful answers. Please let me know if there's any advice.</sub>

---

EDIT) Summing up the comment and answers:

1. use `np.set_printoptions(linewidth=1000)` since `Box2D` has a np.array representation. (`np.set_printoptions` has more options so please check them out)
2. Use pprint: `pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(width=500, compact=True); pp.pprint(...)`
3. Use `np.array2string` if it's np.array. (observation is np.array so this works, but Gymnasium spaces such as `Box` itself are not numpy array so this doesn't work. Though its "representation" seems to be a numpy array so the solution 1 works.)

Comment: Isn't `pprint` what you are looking for? e.g. `pprint(env.observation_space, width=100)`.

Comment: @Memristor Thanks, yes, `pprint` works! The code should be like `pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(width=500, compact=True)` and then `pp.pprint(...)` though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Box2D` has a `np.array` representation. You can therefore use the `np` options for printing:

```py
import numpy as np
import sys
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
```

This line states that there are as many columns printed as possible by the system. If you now apply this to your example, it should print all columns. Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37149933/how-to-set-max-output-width-in-numpy) or the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) if you are stuck.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tested it much, but it seems that the `linewidth` keyword argument is needed such as `np.set_printoptions(linewidth=1000)`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your observations are of type `np.array`, you can use numpy's `array2string` method. E.g.:

```
print(f'initial observation: {np.array2string(observation, precision=3, separator=",")}')
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for the observation since it's indeed a numpy array, but sadly the `np.array2string` doesn't receive `gymnasium.spaces.box.Box` such as `env.observation_space` in this case. But still nice advice! :)