# I'm using my Jupyter notebook in vscode, but it doesn't output, and the output window changes to white and it doesn't respond

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm using my Jupyter notebook in vscode, but it doesn't output, and the output window changes to white and it doesn't respond.(Even if I follow the solution in the stackoverflow, I can't solve it.)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6zGQ.png)

I'm using the M1 macbook air and the Python version is 3.10.5.

I've tried the methods.

- Set InteractiveShell to all,
- Restart the kernel,
- Upgrade/Reinstall Jupiter Notebook,
- Initialize vscode,
- Clear Anaconda

I've been trying to solve this for 3 days, but I haven't been able to... help me....

I've tried the methods.

- Set InteractiveShell to all,
- Restart the kernel,
- Upgrade/Reinstall Jupiter Notebook,
- Initialize vscode,
- Clear Anaconda

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77441295/11107541