# Jupyter Notebook not filling screen

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

My jupyter notebook screen will not fill down to the bottom of my screen. It stops about 2/3 of the way down and it makes viewing my code difficult. Maybe it could be the way I downloaded Anaconda?[What I see in jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZJIR.png)

I came on a few other posts on here but they all just expanded the width and I don't necessarily care about that.

Comment: Did you try adjusting the zoom in your browser? Was it always like this? Please specify the version of Jupyter Notebook you are using? Did you try suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44299923/8508004)?