# How to print a dictionary in jupyter-notebook?

Tags: python, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to print a dictionary in jupyter-notebook and got this:

[image: Screen-Shot-2019-04-20-at-11-44-58-AM.png]

As can be seen, each value in the dictionary is a list of tuples. For the first two keys, the tuples are printed on new lines. However, for the third key, the list of tuples is shown on the same line.

I am wondering what causes this difference in behavior?

Comment: Probably because if they valued for the first 2 keys were to be printed on the same line, those lines would wrap in the output area and look like gibberish. Jupyter is just trying to make things look presentable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of questions on jupyter cell width. You can configure jupyter width to 100% to show longer lines in one line as well. Also take a look at [Jupyter Lab](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/overview.html).

[Jupyter Width Setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971449/how-do-i-increase-the-cell-width-of-the-jupyter-ipython-notebook-in-my-browser)