# Jupyter notebook slideshow - removing white space on sides

Tags: css, jupyter-notebook, reveal.js, nbconvert

I converted my jupyter notebook to slideshow using this command:

```
jupyter nbconvert Jupyter\ "test.ipynb" --to slides --reveal-prefix "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reveal.js/3.1.0"
```

Now, I have an html slide file that I can see my slides. How can I remove/reduce white borders on the right and left side of the each slide?

My problem is different from increasing the cell width of the Jupyter/ipython notebook [How do I increase the cell width of the Jupyter/ipython notebook in my browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971449/how-do-i-increase-the-cell-width-of-the-jupyter-ipython-notebook-in-my-browser)

I searched a lot and was not able to find an answer to this issue.  I appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you asking if the content can expand to take up the entire page?

Comment: Yes I do - when I open the html page,  I have two big vertical white borders.  Unfortunately, I cannot upload any image to clarify better.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `custom.css` file to the same folder you are running the command in and have the contents be something like:

```
.slides {
  width: 90% !important;
}
```

Be careful with tweaking too many styles and setting `!important` flags, as you can quickly get unexpected behavior elsewhere in the converted notebook.