# How to increase jupyter notebook/lab cell widths when outputting to html

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

The following command will create a html file without the code:

```
jupyter nbconvert inspect.ipynb --no-input --no-prompt
```

Where the file is called `inspect.ipynb` and the output of the above is `inspect.html`.

I would like to know how to make the width of the cells in the *output* (not within jupyter lab) wider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place this cell into your notebook:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971449/how-do-i-increase-the-cell-width-of-the-jupyter-ipython-notebook-in-my-browser
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>"))
```

And run you command:

```
jupyter nbconvert inspect.ipynb --no-input --no-prompt
```

Or maybe you can do it with **custom.css**, but I'm not sure. See the second answer in here [How do I increase the cell width of the Jupyter/ipython notebook in my browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971449/how-do-i-increase-the-cell-width-of-the-jupyter-ipython-notebook-in-my-browser)