# How to maximize/fullscreen Kepler GL map within Jupyter notebook?

Tags: kepler.gl

I'm trying to use Kepler GL from within a Jupyter notebook. However the Kepler app is only running withing the relatively small cell output area. Overall I'm wasting a lot of my screen estate and with more complex data the tiny window is quite a showstopper:

[image]

Setting `height` and `width` of the `KeplerGL` constructor doesn't seem to impact the cell size.

Is there a way to maximize the app / go full-screen, or maybe just significantly increase the size of the cell output?

Comment: What about something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34058270/5602923?

Comment: I tried this solution, but it didn't help. Has anybody found another one?