# How to increase the height on jupyter notebook cells

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am trying to visualize a long dictionary in a jupyter notebook. The cell height is too small, so I would like to increase it. I am looking for a simple command that can write in the same cell.

Comment: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34058270/6941952) may help you if you replace `width` by `height`

Comment: I looked this answer before asking, but actually it didn't help me. Makes sense ask for the 100% of the widh, but doesn't for the 100% of the height. I tried to adapt it to my case but it didn't work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a simple way to do this.

The procedure is basically this:

- 1 - Open the folder `~/python-3.9.5.amd64/Lib/site-packages/notebook/static/custom/`
- 2 - In this open folder, open in notepad the file `custom.css`
- 3 - Add to this file the content below:

```html
.container {
    width: 100% !important;
}   

div.notebook-container {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: fit-content;
}  

div.menubar-container {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: fit-content;
}  

div.maintoolbar-container {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: fit-content;
}  

div.cell.selected {
    border-left-width: 1px !important;  
}

div.output_scroll {
    resize: vertical !important;
}

.output_wrapper .output { 
    overflow-y: visible; 
    height: fit-content; 
}


.output_scroll {
    box-shadow:none !important;
    webkit-box-shadow:none !important;
}
```

- 4 - Then, save the modifications in the file and open the Jupyter notebook.