# How to change the style/width of cells in JupyterLab?

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-lab

I tried

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:60% !important; }</style>"))
```

from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34058270/7357673). I also tried

```
%%html
<style>.container { width:60% !important; }</style>
```

but they don't work.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The names of classes were reworked in JupyterLab and are now easier to understand and more predictable. Use the following selectors for JupyterLab:

- `.jp-Cell` to change the width of all cells
- `.jp-Cell.jp-CodeCell` to change only width of the cells with code
- `.jp-Cell.jp-MarkdownCell` to change the width of markdown cells
- `.jp-Cell.jp-Editor` to change width of the editor only
- `.jp-OutputArea-output` to change the with of cell outputs

For example, to reduce the width of cells using IPython you could use:

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.jp-Cell { width: 60% !important; }</style>"))
```

You can use the *DOM inspector*, a tool that all browsers provide nowadays, (see the instructions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools#how_to_open_the_devtools_in_your_browser)) to check class names of specific elements that you wish to modify.

Comment: This works fantastically, just like a charm. Is there anyway to center the cells after we adjust the width?

Comment: It would be great and complete to receive your question to my new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66280016/how-to-center-a-cell-in-jupyterlab-after-its-width-is-decreased).

Comment: The line `display(HTML("<style>.jp-OutputArea-output { width: 100% !important;  margin: 0 auto; }</style>"))` does not work in my JupyterLab. Could you please have a look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66280349/how-to-have-different-widths-of-code-cell-and-output-cell)?