# How to center a cell in JupyterLab after its width is decreased?

Tags: python, html, css, ipython, jupyter-lab

From this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66278615/7357673), I'm able to adjust the width of cells in JupyterLab.

[image]

The result would be perfect if we can center the cells. Could you please elaborate on how to do do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `margin: 0 auto` works as for JupyterLab 3.0:

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.jp-Cell { width: 60% !important; margin: 0 auto; }</style>"))
```

But I believe that questions like that might be counter productive as we already have the CSS positioning perfectly explained in: [How to horizontally center an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-an-element).