# How to have different widths of code cell and output cell?

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x, ipython

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66278615/7357673), I've been able to adjust the widths of code cell and markdown cell independently

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.jp-Cell.jp-CodeCell { width: 70% !important;  margin: 0 auto; }</style>"))
display(HTML("<style>.jp-Cell.jp-MarkdownCell { width: 90% !important;  margin: 0 auto; }</style>"))
```

Then I also want to keep the output cell intact so that I can display big plot with

```
display(HTML("<style>.jp-OutputArea-output { width: 100% !important;  margin: 0 auto; }</style>"))
```

Unfortunately, it does not work

[image]

Could you please elaborate on how to adjust the width of the output cell?

Update: I also tried

```
display(HTML("<style>.jp-Cell.jp-CodeCell.jp-Cell-inputWrapper { width: 70% !important;  margin: 0 auto; }</style>"))
display(HTML("<style>.jp-Cell.jp-CodeCell.jp-Cell-outputWrapper { width: 100% !important;  margin: 0 auto; }</style>"))
```

, but they did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I found the solution

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.jp-CodeCell .jp-Cell-inputWrapper { width: 80% !important;  margin: 0 auto; }</style>"))
display(HTML("<style>.jp-MarkdownCell .jp-Cell-inputWrapper { width: 90% !important;  margin: 0 auto; }</style>"))
display(HTML("<style>.jp-Cell-outputWrapper { width: 100% !important;  margin: 0 auto; }</style>"))
```