# How do I increase the cell width of the Jupyter version 7

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'd like to increse the cell width of the jupyter notebook 7.
I used below code in notebook 6, but it doesn't work in version **7.0.2.**

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>"))
```

Thank you

I want to increase jupyter notebook cell width.

Comment: Try jupyterlab for wider cell width.   There is a button for jupyterlab on the left of menu.

Answer (score 3):

The notebook v7 cell width depends on the padding of notebook element, which's property is set as `calc(calc(100% - var(--jp-notebook-max-width)) * 0.5);`

Override the property --jp-notebook-max-width by adding custom css.

```css
.jp-Notebook {
  --jp-notebook-max-width: 98%;
}
```

about custom.css [Applying custom css](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_css.html)

Answer (score -1):

Changing the CSS [as kimjxie covers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77121968/8508004) will be probably be the best for local installs.
**If you need something more temporary, maybe in a single notebook running on a remote system, then read on**...

There's some helpful information [here, under the title 'How to change the style/width of cells in JupyterLab?'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66278615/8508004); however, you might overlook it unless you know that the current JupyterLab and Notebook Version7+ share the same underlying tech.

---

**Specifically**
For example, to increase the width of cells using IPython in a running notebook you could use:

```py
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.jp-Cell { width: 110% !important; }</style>"))
```

Based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66278615/8508004) & tested in Jupyter Notebook 7.0.1 just now.

---

Tip: Because of the same underlying tech a lot of the tricks and approaches for JupyterLab work in Jupyter Notebook Version7+. Meaning that you'll want to also search for solutions for Jupyter Notebook Version7+ among **recent** posts about JupyterLab.

---

Keep in mind there are other settings you can edit via a form for how the Notebook layout is. To get there go to the Jupyter Dashboard that has the URL that ends in `/tree` (the Dashboard is also where you select files to open) and then under the `Settings` menu click on '`Settings Editor`'. In the '`Settings Editor`' look for '`Notebook`' listed in the side panel and edit the settings in the form. It will look like [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/change-the-cell-size/21712/2?u=fomightez), which discusses changing the margins around the cells.