# Increase width of Jupyter notebook output cell

Tags: numpy, jupyter

How can I increase the width of the Jupyter output cell?  I have an array of arrays (28 x 28) of length 28 each and I want to show each of the 28 arrays on a single line (so I want 28 lines of arrays, each array with 28 items.  As you can see from the attached image, each array is wrapped onto 3 lines, but there seems to be a significant amount of space left on each side of the output cell.  In the second image, I increased the width of the window to 100% and tried to render the output cell again, but still no luck.

I've tried several variations of the following code, but none of them increase the width of the output cell.  It does increase the width of the entire notebook to full screen, but even then the arrays in the output cell maintain the 3 line wrap.

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.jp-OutputArea-output { width:100% !important; }</style>"))
```

[image: Jupyter output cell]
[image: Jupyter output cell #2]

Comment: Please include the version information for your Jupyter Notebook software. There has been a big change introduced with Jupyter Notebook 7+ and this question was already posted for that version, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77030544/8508004). See the second half of [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837597/8508004) if you are not aware of the big recent changes I am alluding to here.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try and edit the CSS file.

```
from jupyter_core.paths import jupyter_config_dir
print(jupyter_config_dir())
```

Navigate to the custom folder in this directory to edit the custom.css file to the changes.

Or try using `jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`:

Installation:

```
pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
```

Enabling the Extension Manager:

```
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```