# Why are my Pandas dataframe columns are being displayed on top of one another instead of horizontally?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with 99 different columns and want to group related topics together for future analysis. However, when I print my new group the columns are not displayed on the same level. They will be stacked on top of one another. It doesn't happen with all columns though. I have tried %pprint but that didn't do anything.

The image below shows the columns I want to call, the other 2 columns are below the first 2 columns. Both have their column name followed by a \ and with the next column displayed at the bottom of the previous column.

[image]

Comment: That's just how it's displayed when the content of the frame (including the column names) is too wide for the notebook. It has nothing to do with the actual shape of the frame.

Answer (score -1):

That's due to Jupyter's restricted print width. I refer to this question: [How do I increase the cell width of the Jupyter/ipython notebook in my browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971449/how-do-i-increase-the-cell-width-of-the-jupyter-ipython-notebook-in-my-browser)

Or you could just rename your columns to something shorter. Cheers!