# Seaborn Heatmap correlation won't fit annotation digits

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I'm trying to plot a triangular correlation matrix using seaborn heatmap but the cells won't fit the annotation digits.

Any idea how I make them fit nicely inside their respective heatmap cell?

I already tried changing the figsize and that did not help. Also tried using square=False.

I'm using seaborn==0.11.2 and matplotlib==3.4.3

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate a dummy df
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(44,44))

label_lens = [16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20, 11,
              9, 10, 10, 16, 16, 16, 16, 12, 45, 10, 10,
             10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 50, 50, 50,
             50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50]

col_labels = []
for label_len in label_lens:
    col_labels.append('X'*label_len)

df.columns = col_labels

# Build correlation matrix df
correlation_matrix = df.corr()

# Get Diagonal Mask. Square matrix is not relevant.
mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(correlation_matrix, dtype=bool))

# Set up the matplotlib figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 15))

# Draw the heatmap with the mask and correct aspect ratio
sns_plot = sns.heatmap(correlation_matrix,
                       mask=mask,
                       annot=True,
                       fmt='.2f',
                       square=True)
f.set_tight_layout(True)
f.savefig("my_corr_matrix.pdf")
```

I replaced my labels here with placeholders of the same sizes as the actual labels.

[image]

Comment: Increase the figure size `f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 20))` and remove `square=True` works with the sample data, but your tick labels are longer so you'll probably need larger than 30

Comment: I tried up to figsize=(90, 60). No luck. The figure gets massive but the annotations still don't fit.

Comment: [Plot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GI3h.png) I can reproduce your issue.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney, please, see the updated code. Now you can reproduce with the dummy labels.

Comment: I said remove `square=True` which you didn't do. `f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 15))` works fine then; needed a little more space with the long ticklabels

Comment: [plot sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCivW.png) looks like it does, and I'm using the same package versions.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Using the exact same code above I'm getting [this](https://postimg.cc/zyYXD5H8) in a macOS

Comment: If you're using a Jupyter Notebook, restart the kernel and clear the outputs. Otherwise I don't know, since I can't reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed in the comments, using `square=False` with `figsize=(30, 15)` fixed the problem.

Answer (score -2):

The issue is that your labels are taking too much space of your jupyter max width. You probably have 2 options, **the first one** `is editing jupyter width` according to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34058270/2970272

The **second one** would be `lowering how much you're using the plot space`, by trimming your labels, lowering the font, removing the colorbar and such. From the code bellow check all the "## HERE" comments to easily find what I've changed.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate a dummy df
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(44,44))

label_lens = [16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20, 11,
              9, 10, 10, 16, 16, 16, 16, 12, 45, 10, 10,
             10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 50, 50, 50,
             50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50]
#label_lens= [5]*len(label_lens)

col_labels = []
for label_len in label_lens:
    col_labels.append(f"{'X'*label_len}"[:10]) ## HERE -- max char limit

df.columns = col_labels

# Build correlation matrix df
correlation_matrix = df.corr()

# Get Diagonal Mask. Square matrix is not relevant.
mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(correlation_matrix, dtype=bool))

# Set up the matplotlib figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 20)) ## here increased figsize

## HERE - max tick font size
ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=8)

# Draw the heatmap with the mask and correct aspect ratio
sns_plot = sns.heatmap(correlation_matrix,
                       mask=mask,
                       annot=True,
                       fmt='.2f',
                       square=True,
                       cbar=False) ## HERE removed colorbar
f.set_tight_layout(True)
## HERE - rotating ticks to give more space
plt.setp(ax.yaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=-45)
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=-45)
plt.show()
#f.savefig("my_corr_matrix.pdf")
```

Comment: Tried that. No luck. The labels went all over the place, including below the cbar.

Comment: @MatheusTorquato, I edited my answer for a different approach than the square=False that would not cramp the data.