# How to make DataFrame display all rows in one line

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am looking for how to make `pandas` displays all rows, each in one line rather than breaking into 2 lines like this

[image]

Comment: Probably your answer is here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-display-all-rows-from-dataframe-using-pandas/#:~:text=A%20function%20set_option()%20is,value%20of%20max_rows%20is%2010.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34058270/11246056