# Display all rows and cols of dataframe with max height and width and scroll bars

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I want to export a notebook to html to share with colleagues, and I would like to display a full (large) dataframe.

My first try was to set:

```py
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

However, the output is too large and it is visually unappealing (and also breaks my custom HTML template). Ideally, I would like to:

- Display the full df contained within a limited width and height
- Have 2 scrollbars (vertical and horizontal) to navigate the whole table
- Avoid "hacky" workarounds and keep it simple, with vscode/pandas/jupyter config

Comment: Check out https://pypi.org/project/itables/.

Comment: @stever Not what I had in mind, but worth it! I'll maintain the question open, as I would like a solution without requiring external modules. Thank you!

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34058270/11246056