# How do I fix cell and output width in JupyterLab?

Tags: jupyter-lab

I have a problem with max cell width in JupyterLab. When too many characters are inputted the cell shows a horizontal slider, but also increases in width. The slider amplitude is minimal (a couple of characters) and remains constant as the as the cell widens. This is also true for outputs, such as `pandas` dataframes with a lot of columns. I have tried reinstalling JupyterLab and solutions from other threads such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971449/how-do-i-increase-the-cell-width-of-the-jupyter-ipython-notebook-in-my-browser) but nothing seems to work.

[image]

Comment: This does not seem right. What version of JupyterLab it is?

Comment: @krassowski It's version 3.3.2