# How to increase Google Colab cell output width?

Tags: python, html, css, pandas, google-colaboratory

I found a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971449/how-do-i-increase-the-cell-width-of-the-jupyter-ipython-notebook-in-my-browser) but the solution did not work on Google colab. I would like to see better the text in my pandas dataframes columns. Right now the default width seems 50%.

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>"))
display(HTML("<style>.output_result { max-width:100% !important; }</style>"))
```

As an alternative, I found an extension called [Data Tables](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/data_table.ipynb#scrollTo=3jcHW3nRJpaE). This may be the best solution available today for it but seems to only works for tables.

```
from google.colab import data_table
data_table.enable_dataframe_formatter()
```

Answer (score 3):

Was able to increase pandas display output in Colab using:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.width', 180)
```