# How to remove leading whitespace from table markdown?

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have table markdown which looks as below:

```
| Horizonal | Vertical |
| :-      | :-   |
| abc       | def      |
```

The above markdown is showing leading whitespaces in the jupyter notebook.

How can I remove the leading whitespaces in jupyter notebook?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ipython notebook align table to the left of cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892570/ipython-notebook-align-table-to-the-left-of-cell)

Comment: Where is the leading whitespace? Do you mean that there is a few pixels padding?